# How can I find a file path by its name in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need a automatic file finder in my current project, like entering the name and finding the path.

The only samples I found was finding file's name by its path. I want the reverse version of it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I recommend you read the [Ask] section of the Help Center. There, you will read that Stack Overflow questions should be aimed towards *What you have tried, and why and what about your attempt isn't working* .

Comment: Please use Google or Bing to search for programming questions, Disney.com or Netflix.com are less likely to give you good results for coding questions. I.e. https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+how+can+i+find+a+file+path+by+its+name

Answer (score 1):

You can search with this:

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "file-you-are-looking.bmp", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Comment: This shows how to search for the files, but doesn't show how to return the full path for the file. It's a start- but I don't believe this would be a full answer to the question without more application